# JQueryMobile, Autocomplete and vertical scrollbar on iPAD safari

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Autocomplete on my jQUeryMobile application. It works perfect. Now I'm trying to show vertical scrollbar to scroll through the list of looked up items. The scrollbar shows up on desktop safari, but not on iPAD safari. my css looks like this:

```
<style>
    .ui-autocomplete 
    {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */
        overflow-x: hidden;
        max-width:70%;
    }
</style>
```

Can someone help, thanks!

Comment: knock knock..Houston, we still have this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your style:

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

Put the above style in CSS document of class body.....